# How do I FTP multiple files at the same time ( parallel) from UNIX

Tags: unix

We have to transfer 10 files in parallel from a unix using shell script via FTP.

Comment: As of now we are using mput. which places the files one by one

Answer (score 1):

Just put download process in the background appending ampersand:

```
wget --ftp-user=*** --ftp-password=*** ftp://server/file_A 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null&
wget --ftp-user=*** --ftp-password=*** ftp://server/file_B 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null&
wget --ftp-user=*** --ftp-password=*** ftp://server/file_C 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null&
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ftp server doesn't impose any limits to the number of concurrent connections, you can run many ftp sessions in background. E.g. (note: I'll assume a generic gnu-like ftp client, command line options and input strings may be different):

```
for i in file1 file2 file3 ... file10; do
  echo "get $i" | ftp $ServerHost --user $username --password "$xxx" --binary >/dev/null 2>&1 &
done
wait
```